# How to add a new line using ngbToolTip with attribute binding

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have searched but have not found any of the solutions helpful. As other people have said, the \n, br, \r, or &#013 does not work. I am using a function to call the tooltip for each of my dates on the calendar since I have to loop through an array of recurrences.

ts file

```
getToolTip(x: Date) {
    let retR = [];
    let d3 = x.getDay();
      let dt2 = this.recurrances.filter(e =>
        (e.recurrances == 2 && d3 == 1) ||
        (e.recurrances == 3 && d3 == 2) ||
        (e.recurrances == 4 && d3 == 3) ||
        (e.recurrances == 5 && d3 == 4) ||
        (e.recurrances == 6 && d3 == 5));
        dt2.forEach(e=> retR.push(e));

    let ret = ""
    retR.forEach(e=> {
      ret = "Company: " + e.company + "\n" +"Description: " + e.description;
       
    });
    return ret;
  }
```

html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entries.length > 0 || appointments.length > 0 || recurrances.length > 0">
   <tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
     <td class='days'  (click)="showTimeEntries(d)" *ngFor="let d of w">
       <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
         <h4>{{getHours(d)}}</h4>
         <h5 [ngbTooltip]="getToolTip(d)" [openDelay]="400">{{ getAppointments(d) }}</h5>
     </td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You're aware you reassign `ret` every loop now, right? It will only get the last value of retR.

Comment: Anyway, I'd use a templateRef instead of calling a function that returns a string, and use br there. That should work

Comment: You shouldn't use a function binding like '[ngbTooltip]="getToolTip(d)"'

Comment: @ShamPooSham Is there a better way to not reassign ret every loop?

Comment: By reassigning at every loop, you'll just get the last value in the end. If that's what you want to do, you can simply do `const e = retR[ retR.length - 1 ]; const ret = "Company: " + e.company + "\n" +"Description: " + e.description;`

Comment: But it's hard for me to help you with this code sample if I can't see the rest of the code. I don't know what `this.recurrances` contains. Do you ever get more than one element in `retR`?

Comment: @ShamPooSham this.recurrances is bascially showing all of my appointments that have a recurrence in an array. I do get more than one element for both retR and retA. What I want to do is show all the appointments in retA to show on the calendar but as you said, I am only getting the last one in the array. Maybe I should start a new thread with that question...

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith Yes, it's a good idea to create a new thread for that. Send me the link when you have posted it and I will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-template to achieve the multiple lines of the content:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whu8aq?file=src/app/tooltip-tplcontent.html

```
<ng-template #tipContent>
  tooltip <br>
  mulitple <br>
  lines!
</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">
  Check tooltip
</button>
```

BTW, you should avoid using function binding like:

```
[ngbTooltip]="getToolTip(d)"
```